# Calling a method to return a different int from a switch

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I'm trying to call a method and based on the input, return that value to a switch I have in another class. So if I were to choose the "1" element in my array, I would get reply returned as "4" back into my other class and make it run switch "4".

In the other class I have the switch "4" set to another method. However, I keep getting the int value "1" returned from my method as it keeps calling that method (switch "1"). Which makes sense since it's the "1" element in my array, it should then run switch "1", but I thought that by setting "reply = 4", it would return an int "4" into my other class and thus invoke switch "4".

How do I get my methods to return the value I want so I can put into my switch?

Here's my first class where I'm doing the calling:

```
package bunnyhunt;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Messages {

//Objects 
public Rooms roomCall = new Rooms();

//Instance Variables
public static boolean gameOver = false;
public static int roomNum;
public static int reply;
boolean visitedOtherRoom = false;

//Constructors    
//Methods    
public void start() {

//while loop
    while (gameOver == false) {

//do-while loop
        do {
            String[] parkEntrance = {"Spring Meadow", "Aeryn's Overlook", "Garden Gate"};
            reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're at the Park Entrance! What do you want to do?", "Bunny Adventure", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, parkEntrance, parkEntrance[0]);

            switch (reply) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("oh man...Spring");
                    visitedOtherRoom = true;
                    roomCall.springMeadow();

                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("oh man...Aeryn");
                    visitedOtherRoom = true;
                    roomCall.aerynsOverlook();

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("oh man...Garden");
                    visitedOtherRoom = true;
                    roomCall.gardenGate();

                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("error");

            }

        } while (visitedOtherRoom == false);

        switch (reply) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("second 0!!!");
                visitedOtherRoom = true;
                roomCall.parkEntrance();

                break;
            case 1:
                visitedOtherRoom = true;
                System.out.println("yes man!");
                roomCall.aerynsOverlook();
                break;

            case 2:
                visitedOtherRoom = true;
                roomCall.gardenGate();

                break;

            case 3:
                visitedOtherRoom = true;
                roomCall.peacefulPond();

                break;

            case 4:
                visitedOtherRoom = true;
                roomCall.readingNook();

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("default");

        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Game Over!!!");
}

}
```

and my second where the things I call reside:

```
package bunnyhunt;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Rooms {


public static int reply;

public int springMeadow() {

     String[] springMeadow = {"Park Entrance", "Reading Nook",                   "Search"};
    Messages.reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're in the    Spring Meadow! What do you want to do?", "Spring Meadow", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, springMeadow, springMeadow[0]);

    switch (reply) {
        case 0:

            reply = 0;

            break;
        case 1:

            reply = 4;
            break;

        case 2:

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "You searched!");

            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("error");

    }


    return reply;

}

public int aerynsOverlook() {
 String[] aerynsOverlook = {"Park Entrance", "Peaceful Pond",   "Search"};
    Messages.reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're in    Aeryn's Overlook! What do you want to do?", "Aeryn's Overlook", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, aerynsOverlook, aerynsOverlook[0]);

    return reply;

}

public int gardenGate() {

   String[] gardenGate = {"Park Entrance", "Rose Gardent", "Butterfly Garden", "Flowering Forest"};
     return reply;

}

public int readingNook() {

    String[] readingNook = {"Spring Meadow", "Search"};
    Messages.reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're in the Reading Nook! What do you want to do?", "Reading Nook", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, readingNook, readingNook[0]);
    return reply;

}

public int parkEntrance() {

    String[] parkEntrance = {"Spring Meadow", "Aeryn's Overlook", "Search"};
    Messages.reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're in the Park Entrance! What do you want to do?", "Park Entrance", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, parkEntrance, parkEntrance[0]);
    return reply;
}

public int peacefulPond() {

    String[] peacefulPond = {"Raven's Tower", "Aeryn's Overlook", "Search"};
    Messages.reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "You're in the Peaceful Pond! What do you want to do?", "Peaceful Pond", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, peacefulPond, peacefulPond[0]);
    return reply;
}

}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you return the `reply` variable?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis actually do have it! Sorry, it was just at the bottom after some commented out code.

Comment: a variable (`reply`) declared in one class is not the same as declared in another class

Comment: that is, you are not using the returned value from `springMeadow` - maybe this works `reply = roomCall.springMeadow();` , same for others cases

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a `reply` value from the `start()` method since this method is void AND `switch` statements inside don't return anything, despite they contain calls to appropriate methods like `int aerynsOverlook(). You should modify`start` method like this:

```
public int start() {
    ...
    switch (reply) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("oh man...Spring");
                visitedOtherRoom = true;
                return roomCall.springMeadow();
...
```

Secondly, I don't see how you are calling `start()` method to get its return value and use it in the second switch. Your `MEssages` class doesn't have any connection with the `Rooms`

Comment: I actually do have it!, it was at the bottom of some commented out code. Thanks for the catch though.

Comment: Please, update your code and also show us how you are calling the second switch with the value from first

Comment: I added the whole both classes, just so all the info is there. I think one of my problems may be the do-while loop I have going on that's throwing everything off.

Comment: that seems not to be the problems solution, it is more that the returned value should be assigned to `reply` which is used in the second switch statement

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer, thanks! The code has much more other issues though ...